# Как правильно хранить список данных для каждого пользователя

Tags: mysql, node.js, mongodb

Всем привет, пишу мейлер на nodejs, стал такой вопрос: у меня будет скажем 100 пользователей, у каждого свой кабинет, в кабинете он сможет импортировать свои smtp сервера их может быть 10 а может и 1000, где правильно хранить эту информацию и как. C помощью базы данных я не пойму как это сделать правильно, буду благодарен за подсказку

Comment: Правильно: хранить в БД. Например сделай 2 таблицы users, smptServers. Связь у таблиц 1 ко многим по полю, например user_id. Выбор самой СУБД - в данном случае роли особой не играет

Comment: *свои smtp сервера их может быть 10 а может и 1000* Правильный ответ зависит от того, возможна ли ситуация совпадения - когда один и тот же SMTP регистрируется несколькими пользователями.  Если да - налицо M:N, требующая связующей таблицы. Ну а если нет, то см. комментарий @SwaD. Впрочем, с учётом существующих реалий, скорее всего будет именно M:N, причём в таблице серверов будут храниться общие атрибуты (типа адрес, порты, набор протоколов, адреса абьюза и пр.), а в связующей таблице частные (логин и пароль пользователя и пр.).